# Sqoop - Syntaxt error - Boundary Query - "error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql, sqoop, boundary

I am tryin to load some data from MYSQL into Hive table using Sqoop. I have some conditions on boundary query. My command is:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba --password cloudera --table order_items --boundary-query "SELECT 1,10 FROM order_items WHERE $CONDITIONS" --split-by order_id --hive-import --hive-home /user/cloudera/hive --hive-table default.order_items2 --create-hive-table
```

And when I execute my command it gives the following error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Do you know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the value for `$CONDITIONS`? How have you set it? Where have you set it? And what command line are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify $CONDITIONS in where clause